# How to model this dataset?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, dependent-variable

I'm working with a dataset (`my_dataset`) that comprises six groups of individuals (`Team_ID`) with a dependent variable `Score` representing the group's performance score (ranging between 0 and 1). The dataset includes various individual-level characteristics such as demographic information, education, employment status, and income. Here's a simplified version of the dataset:

```r
Team_ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)
Score <- c(0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.1, 0.1, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.65, 0.65, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.24, 0.24)
    Intercept <- rep(1, length(Team_ID))
    D1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    D2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    D3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    D4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    D5 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    Sex <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    Age <- c(38, 39, 44, 60, 29, 18, 34, 19, 43, 56, 35, 25, 43, 31, 51, 55, 54, 28, 53)
    Educ <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)
    Emp_Unemp <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
Income <- c(457.37, 1267.59, 3304.82, 1143.71, 2800.09, 1149.06, 1377.78, 1882.33, 2095.88, 2667.53, 592.9, 944.27, 1479.07, 1764.27, 1062.84, 788.15, 1882.96, 1315.33, 1410.25)
Marital_Status <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    
my_dataset <- data.frame(Team_ID, Score, Intercept, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, Sex, Age, Educ, Emp_Unemp, Income, Marital_Status)
```

I want to estimate the individual contributions to the group scores, considering the characteristics provided. I have two main concerns:

1. Repetition of `Score`: From an econometric standpoint, does the fact that `Score` is repeated within each group raise concerns? How should I address this in my modeling process? Notice that I added group fixed effects.
2. Modeling Constrained `Score`: Since the `Score` variable is constrained between 0 and 1 and follows a normal distribution, how can I appropriately model this variable, taking this into account?

Edit:
I aim to:

- Calculate the predicted score based on individual characteristics.
- Compute the difference $\hat{\varepsilon}$ between the observed score ($Y$) and the predicted score $\hat{Y}$.
- Interpret this difference as the "residual" or the "group synergy effect."

Given that `Score` is a truncated normal distribution between 0 and 1, would it be more appropriate to apply Logit or Beta regression for this analysis?

Comment: Why is the `score`  repeated in groups? How is it measured?

Comment: The score is the “grade” obtained by the groups components.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to estimate the individual contributions to the group scores, considering the characteristics provided.

It seems that you’re looking for the posterior probability $\Pr(S=s|\boldsymbol X = \boldsymbol x)$ of having score $s$ given individual feature vector $\boldsymbol x_i = (\mathit{D1}_i, \dots, \mathit{MaritalStatus}_i)$. It will tell you how each feature value makes a certain score more or less likely.

> 1. Repetition of Score: … does the fact that Score is repeated within each group raise concerns?

Where does the score repeat? Each line of your code gives, for each feature (variable), a vector whose component $i$ is the value for the $i$-th individual. It happens that each individual of the same group has the same score. Unless you have wrong data, it is what it is. However, of course, the team ID shouldn’t be taken in a predictive analysis as we could directly determine the score from it.

Also, look at D2, are you concerned by the fact that value 0 repeats?

> 2. Modeling Constrained Score: Since the Score variable is constrained between 0 and 1 and follows a normal distribution

Do you assume a truncated normal distribution with $\mu \in (0, 1)$ and $\sigma$ small enough so that $f_S(0) = f_S(1) \approx 0$?

> how can I appropriately model this variable, taking this into account?

IMHO, you can perform a Bayesian analysis. For instance, you could:

- Estimate, based on the data, any regression model that gives you a decision function $\hat f \colon \boldsymbol X \mapsto S$ that minimizes any appropriate loss/risk function (MSE, etc.). Since scores go from 0 to 1, you could use a logistic regression.
- Identify a reasonable normal prior of $X$ (using the data if needed).
- Apply the decision function to the prior to get the posterior distribution of $S$ given each feature of $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n)$.

Or, given $\hat f$, you could just comment on the coefficients of your regression model.

Comment: I edited my question since the objective of my analysis was not clear. I don't want to calculate the posterior probability, but the predicted and residual score based on the characteristics.

Comment: Ok so the fact that the score is at the group level and that the characteristics are at the individual level does not cause problems? To be clear, this data set is similar to a panel data where in place of the temporal dimension there is the individual dimension. (Of course the Team ID is only an index)

Comment: Then it comes down to just estimate $\hat f$. Without any assumption except that scores are in $[0,1]$, I would fit a logistic regression to predict the score based on D1 down to marital status. Then the predicted scores are obtained during the fitting process, and the residuals are simply the predicted scores minus the actual scores (for each individual). However, the residuals doesn’t tell you how the individual features contribute to the score. It just tells you if your regression model is well fitted. You’ll have to look at the model coefficients to know the contribution of each feature.

Comment: Not the residuals, the fitted values. $Y$ is the observed score $\hat{Y}$ is the predicted score based on individual characteristics, $Y-\hat{Y} = \hat{\varepsilon}$ is the unexplained score (unexplained by individual characteristics). Am I wrong?

Comment: "score is at the group level and … characteristics are at the individual level" You want to predict the score for each individual, so there is only the individual level. Look at variable `TeamID`: it gives the group of each individual. It’s the same for `Score`: it gives the group of each individual. That doesn’t prevent you from doing any stats about it. That `TeamID` isn’t even a variable in your analysis.

Comment: "$Y-\hat Y =\hat\varepsilon$ is the unexplained score" Yes, we call that the residuals. It tells you how your model is wrong about the data. All this is synonym. Not being able to explain = making a prediction error. So it may be what you’re looking for. But just in case, I precise that it doesn’t tell you how each features contributes to the score. I tell this because the initial question sounds like you’re looking for these contribution coefficients.

Comment: Ok I was thinking to employ logistic regression or beta regression. In this case beta regression isn't more appropriate? I am not an expert of glm even less of bayesian statistics, but I can delve into them if you suggest to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150140/discussion-between-barbab-and-alexandre-huat).